# SQL Server 2008 query to get sales count for every seller and status

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
UserID      Processed   Approved    Declined    Returned
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           5           1           2           2
2           3           1           2           0
5           5           1           2           3
8           4           1           2           1
9           6           1           2           3
11          7           1           2           4
12          8           1           2           1
```

But I'm currently getting this:

```
UserID      Processed   Approved    Declined    Returned
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           4           1           2           1
2           4           1           2           1
5           4           1           2           1
8           4           1           2           1
9           4           1           2           1
11          4           1           2           1
12          4           1           2           1
```

I'm new to SQL and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my select:

```
SELECT u.UserID,
(SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM  [dbo].[Krdocs_Details] d, [dbo].[Krdocs] e, [dbo].[Statuses] f
WHERE d.Id=e.Id AND f.Code = d.KrStatus AND ((d.KrStatus = 80) OR (d.KrStatus BETWEEN 60 AND 61) OR (d.KrStatus = 70 OR d.KrStatus BETWEEN 90 AND 92))) AS Processed,
(SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM  [dbo].[Krdocs_Details] d, [dbo].[Krdocs] e, [dbo].[Statuses] f
WHERE d.Id=e.Id AND f.Code = d.KrStatus AND d.KrStatus = 80) AS Approved,
(SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM  [dbo].[Krdocs_Details] d, [dbo].[Krdocs] e, [dbo].[Statuses] f
WHERE d.Id=e.Id AND f.Code = d.KrStatus AND (d.KrStatus = 70 OR d.KrStatus BETWEEN 90 AND 92)) AS Declined,
(SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM  [dbo].[Krdocs_Details] d, [dbo].[Krdocs] e, [dbo].[Statuses] f
WHERE d.Id=e.Id AND f.Code = d.KrStatus AND (d.KrStatus BETWEEN 60 AND 61)) AS Returned
FROM [dbo].[Krdocs_Details] d, [dbo].[Krdocs] e, [dbo].[Statuses] f, [dbo].[bsUsers] u
WHERE d.Id=e.Id AND f.Code=d.KrStatus and u.UserID = d.UserProcess
GROUP BY u.UserID
ORDER BY u.UserID
```

Comment: Could you please provide your table structures and some sample data? Furthermore you are not restricting to user, so it's always the same value for all users.

Comment: In your sub queries to get a sum, you are not restricting the data to a specific user.

Comment: @RossBush But I want all the users in the same query.

Comment: each of your sub queries needs to have ` and d.UserProcess = u.UserID` added to the where clause.. at the same time, your from clause can be simply `From bsUsers u`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a query like the following.  If you  post sample data for desired output I can test / modify it.

Hints: - use JOIN syntax instead of WHERE for joining table; - try to avoid to access several times the same table (like using SELECT inside a field = SELECT as you did)

```
SELECT u.USERID
    , SUM (CASE WHEN d.KrStatus IN (60,61,70,80,90,91,92)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PROCESSED
    , SUM (CASE WHEN d.KrStatus IN (80)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS APPROVED
    , SUM (CASE WHEN d.KrStatus IN (70,90,91,92)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECLINED
    , SUM (CASE WHEN d.KrStatus IN (60,61)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RETURNED
FROM Krdocs_Details D
INNER JOIN Krdocs E ON  D.Id=E.Id
INNER JOIN Statuses F ON D.KrStatus=F.Code
INNER JOIN bsUsers U ON D.UserProcess = U.UserID
WHERE d.KrStatus IN (60,61,70,80,90,91,92) 
GROUP BY u.UserID
ORDER BY u.UserID;
```

or, if you prefer avoid one repetition

```
SELECT userID
, APPROVED+DECLINED+RETURNED AS PROCESSED 
, APPROVED
, DECLINED
, RETURNED
FROM (SELECT u.USERID    
    , SUM (CASE WHEN d.KrStatus IN (80)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS APPROVED
    , SUM (CASE WHEN d.KrStatus IN (70,90,91,92)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECLINED
    , SUM (CASE WHEN d.KrStatus IN (60,61)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RETURNED
    FROM Krdocs_Details D
    INNER JOIN Krdocs E ON  D.Id=E.Id
    INNER JOIN Statuses F ON D.KrStatus=F.Code
    INNER JOIN bsUsers U ON D.UserProcess = U.UserID
    WHERE d.KrStatus IN (60,61,70,80,90,91,92) 
    GROUP BY u.UserID) A
ORDER BY UserID
```

Comment: I forgot in both queries the general WHERE condition.  Now added in answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to split your query down to several ctes, such as the following:

```
WITH cteProcessed AS(
  SELECT d.UserProcess, COUNT(*) cnt 
  FROM  [dbo].[Krdocs_Details] d, [dbo].[Krdocs] e, [dbo].[Statuses] f
  WHERE d.Id=e.Id
    AND f.Code = d.KrStatus
    AND ((d.KrStatus = 80) OR (d.KrStatus BETWEEN 60 AND 61) OR (d.KrStatus = 70 OR d.KrStatus BETWEEN 90 AND 92))
  GROUP BY d.UserProcess
),
cteApproved AS(
  SELECT d.UserProcess, COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM  [dbo].[Krdocs_Details] d, [dbo].[Krdocs] e, [dbo].[Statuses] f
  WHERE d.Id=e.Id AND f.Code = d.KrStatus AND d.KrStatus = 80
  GROUP BY d.UserProcess
),
```

You might want to repeat this for your other queries. Afterwards, you can query your user table and join it to your ctes.

```
SELECT u.UserID, p.cnt processed_count, a.cnt approved_cnt
  FROM [dbo].[bsUsers] u
  LEFT JOIN cteProcessed p ON u.UserProcess = u.UserID
  LEFT JOIN cteApproved a ON u.UserProcess = a.UserID
```